# Web Extension: is there any way to pass an Event object from BrowserAction to Background Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an event for `paste` in a BrowserAction and I need to send either the `Event` object or its `clipboardData.items` property to a Background Script.

I've tried extracting the contents, but it doesn't retain the properties / methods.

Any normal object works, but `Event` objects do not retain their values.

I've also tried deep copies using `Object.assign`, but the contents are never passed to the Background script when using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`.

Really appreciate the help as all my work goes to the trash if I can't get this to work.

My goal is to read an image file from the clipboard and then upload it to a website. Here's the relevant code to the problem I have:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');

body.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  const item = [...event.clipboardData.items].pop();
  const message = {
    fn: 'pasteEvent',
    text: item
  }
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
});
```

Comment: No, DOM events aren't JSON-compatible so you can't send them. Either read the items data and encode it into a string (or a blob object URL) or use the new asynchronous Clipboard API. Your extension will probably need `"clipboardRead"` permission in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the help, but I have no idea how to go about that. My goal is to read an image from the clipboard and then upload it to a website. I would use Clipboard API but, according to the MDN docs, Firefox doesn't support the `read` method (it treats it as `readText`).

Comment: Uhm, the first method I suggested was to read the image any way you can in the popup, then send the encoded data as a string into the background script.

Comment: How do I go about encoding the data into a string? I've never done that before and I sure as heck don't know what methods I would use to go about that.

Comment: I don't know either at the moment so let me [google it up](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+image+data+from+clipboard) and find something like [this](/a/51586232). I don't know if it'll work for you so keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out: you can't pass anything through `runtime.sendMessage` that can't be serialized.

So, the workaround I used was to create a `DOMString` Object URL that represents the file, pass it through `sendMessage`, then download it on the other end. I'm not sure if this was the best way, but it worked.

Step 1: Get the clipboard item as a file:

```
const item = [...event.clipboardData.items].pop();
const blob = item.getAsFile();
```

Step 2: Convert it to an [Object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

`const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

Step 3: After you append it to your message and send it, you have to download the file and specify a response type of `blob`. I used Axios, but you can use whatever:

```
async function getFile(objUrl) {
  const config = {
    responseType: 'blob'
  };
  const res = await axios.get(objUrl, config);
  return res.data;
}
```